# Holes after ST_Split with PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I want to split polygons with multilines, and merge results with the neighboring polygon.

I tried with this code :

```
--Polygon splitting
CREATE TABLE decoupe AS
SELECT rect.affectatio, (
    ST_Dump(
        ST_Split(rect.geom, st_union(line.geom)
                )
    )
).geom as geom
FROM total_avant_decoupe as rect, 
ensemble as line 
GROUP BY rect.geom, rect.affectatio;

--Merging with neighboring polygon
CREATE TABLE fusionvoisinmajoritaire AS
WITH tempo AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, ST_Union(geom) as geom, affectatio
        FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (b.id) a.id, b.id AS idb, ST_Union(a.geom, b.geom) as geom, a.affectatio
        FROM (
            SELECT * 
            FROM fusiondifference
            WHERE affectatio != 'non intersecte'
        ) a JOIN (
            SELECT * 
            FROM fusiondifference 
            WHERE affectatio = 'non intersecte'
        ) b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
        WHERE ST_Length(
                ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)
            ) > 0.05*ST_Perimeter(b.geom)
    ) AS sub
    GROUP BY id, affectatio
)
SELECT * 
FROM tempo
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM fusiondifference
    WHERE affectatio != 'non intersecte'
) AS sub
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM tempo
);
```

But with my splitting code, I get holes between my polygons. So in many case, it can't be merge with my merging code...

I tried also by snapping with ST_SnapToGrid and ST_Snap with the neighboring polygon but it doesn't work, I keep holes.

How to split my polygons without create holes between them? I'm using PostGIS 2.5.3.

EDIT (13/12/2019) :

This is a schema of that I want to do :

[image: schema of that I want to do]

I have 3 options :

- The first is simple, just one adjacent polygon, no split needed
- The second just needed to split polygon by single lines
- The third is little more complex. I create lines with ST_ApproximateMedialAxis amongst others. This requires two steps for the external polygons who haven't neighboor.

Make lines (in red) is not a problem. But the holes creates by splitting...

EDIT 2 (16/12/2019):

For illustrate, when I merge all polygons in one, I obtain this type of polygon, that show the splitting code make holes :

[image: polygon merge]

Comment: I hope this his clearer with my edit

Comment: Could you add to your question a WKB or WKT representation of one of these polygons? I think I have seen this issue before and was able to fix it using an ST_ExteriorRing or a 0-width ST_Buffer operation but I don't want to post it as an answer until I'm sure it works.